# Unable to read superblock on virtual server

Tags: linux, filesystems, ubuntu-14.10

After booting ubuntu 14.10 I got log output like this

**[1377286.486802] EXT4-fs (sda2): unable to read superblock**

I can login and use the machine but I guess something is wrong.

Some diagnostics using fdisk, dumpe2fs and e2fsck were made.

**How bad is this and what should/can be done?**

*sudo fdisk -l*

```
Disk /dev/sda: 16 GiB, 17179869184 bytes, 33554432 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x71f43c62

Device     Boot  Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *      2048   499711   497664  243M 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       501758 33552383 33050626 15.8G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       501760 33552383 33050624 15.8G 8e Linux LVM

Disk /dev/mapper/Ubuntu--vg-root: 11.8 GiB, 12624855040 bytes, 24657920 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk /dev/mapper/Ubuntu--vg-swap_1: 4 GiB, 4294967296 bytes, 8388608 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

*sudo dumpe2fs /dev/sda2*

```
dumpe2fs 1.42.10 (18-May-2014)
dumpe2fs: Attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in short read while trying to open /dev/sda2
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.
```

*sudo e2fsck -f /dev/sda2*

```
e2fsck 1.42.10 (18-May-2014)
e2fsck: Attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in short read while trying to open /dev/sda2

Could this be a zero-length partition?
```

Comment: I just installed Ubuntu 15.10 server on an ESXI host. The default configuration left me with the exact same situation.

Answer (score 2):

Well, yeah, you're trying to mount an extended partition, which is never going to end well -- there is no filesystem on that partition.  What partition did you want to mount, instead?

Comment: Also he needs to activate logical volumes.

Comment: There's no indication that the LVs aren't active.

Comment: Do you mean that I got the log message because the system have tried to mount /dev/sda? My guess in that case is that /dev/sda5 only should be used. From where would such a wrong mount operation come from? Are there a script where I possibly could disable it?

Comment: No, `/dev/sda5` shouldn't be used, because it's an LVM PV, not a filesystem.  A wrong mount operation happens when the system is misconfigured.  Whatever you misconfigured, undo that.

Comment: I just installed Ubuntu 15.10 server on an ESXI host. The default configuration left me with the exact same situation.